# How to identify SD card reader from removable devices in c++ windows?

Tags: c++, windows, sd-card

I want to differentiate between `pen-drives` and an `SD card reader` Since both are in the same category as `Removable Devices`.

I have used `UINT GetDriveTypeA(lpRootPathName)` to know the device type and from this, I found the category of devices.

when the return value of `GetDriveTypeA` function is `2` then the corresponding device is REMOVABLE.

But next how to differentiate between normal `pen-drives` and `SD card reader` since both fall in the same category.

Is there any way to achieve this?

I will be very thankful to you.

Answer (score 0):

SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryPropertyA will get you ahead, with SPDRP_DEVICEDESC as third argument:

```
SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryPropertyA(hDevInfo, DevInfoData, SPDRP_DEVICEDESC, &Data, (PBYTE)buf, sizeof(buf), &size);
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/setupapi/nf-setupapi-setupdigetdeviceregistrypropertya